# Firebase function Cannot find module 'cycle'

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, package.json, linux-mint

When I try to run any firebase command I get this error.

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:596
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'cycle'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:594:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase- tools/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/common.js:11:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
```

I am on

node.js version v10.5.0

npm version 6.1.0

OS Linux Mint 18.3

Comment: Add package.json in your question

Comment: Hi Bob. Im currently having the same problem - did you solve it?

Comment: Unfortunately not, taking some time today to look into.

Comment: I have found a fix. The global install for firebase was missing the modules.

Answer (score 0):

The files in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules are not being updated and installed as expected. Many of the modules are missing.

I had installed firebase locally into what I am going to use as my firebase directory. All of the modules where there. So I copied the files from the local node_modules folder to the global node_modules folder.

To note, this is a bandage to the problem as anytime you go to update firebase you will need to repeat this process.